# Facebook API request even though FB usernam does not exist

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am requesting data from a few different Facebook Like Pages in one request. If one Pages' ID is not correct, for some reason, the request fails:

```
{
   "error": {
  "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist:    asd121233,das3b12s",
      "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 803
   }
}
```

Is there a way to request those IDs that are "correct". I could request every page (cron job) to see if the IDs are correct, but that would be unnecessary if there is a way to request data even though one ID does not exist.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unclear what are you asking for ...

Comment: Lets say I have 10 Facebook Like Page IDs. One if them is not registered, and therefore the ID does not work. Is there a way to request data from multiple IDs eventhough one ID does not work?

Comment: Yes, why not? you can run a loop through an array of the ids and check them one by one

Comment: Lets say I'm requesting "about" from 100 different Like Pages and I want to minimize the execution time. If I do a loop which runs 100 times and does 100 different requests the loadtime becomes a problem.

So I would like to do one request with all the IDs (to minimize the load time). But if one single ID does not correct (a like page could have been deleted) the requests fail.

I'm requesting the data through: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/$ids&fields=about&access_token=$token" and I am wondering if you can type something in the URL to make the request work eventhoug 1 ID does not "work".

Answer (score 0):

`Batch` requests can help, you `POST` your `GET` queries to `/?batch` endpoint (as encoded `JSON`), the response will return as:

[image: r($batch)],

each array contains a `GET` query you requests you can access data using `$batch[{index}]['body']['{desired_field}']`

```
<?php

 $access_token = '{app_id}|{app_secret}'; // a valid user or an app access_token

  $queries = array(
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/google?fields=about,name'),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/fiverras3t5wv4tbsdf?fields=about,name'), // this page doesn't exist for sure
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/designtaxi?fields=about,name'),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/smashmag?fields=about,name'),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/XstackoverflowX?fields=about,name'), // this page doesn't exist for sure
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/asd121233?fields=about,name'), // this page doesn't exist for sure
    );

  $p = array('access_token' => $access_token);

  $batch = api('/?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST', $p);

  foreach ($batch as $response) { // loop check each inner response

    if ($response['code'] == '200') { // if the graph has returned data

       $response = json_decode($response['body'], true);

       print '<p>About '. $response['name'].': ' . $response['about'].'</p>'.PHP_EOL;

    } else { // the pages doesn't exists (404 bad request)

       print '<p>The page doesn\'t exists'.'</p>'.PHP_EOL;

    }
  }

function api( $path, $method = NULL, $params = NULL) {

    $apiCall = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0' . $path;
             // Initiate the cURL extension
             $ch = curl_init();
                       // Check if the method is GET or POST
                       if ( is_null($method) ) {

                             curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, false );
                             if ( is_null($params) ) {
                             // NO PARAMS
                             } else {
                             $apiCall .= '?' . http_build_query($params);
                             // echo 'NULL:'.$apiCall;
                             }

                        } else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

                             curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, false );
                             if ( is_null($params) ) {
                             // NO PARAMS
                             } else {
                             $apiCall .= '?' . http_build_query($params);
                             // echo 'GET: '.$apiCall;
                             }

                       } else if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

                             curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
                             // Check if any params are set
                             if ( is_null($params) ) {
                             // NO PARAMS
                             } else {
                             $params = http_build_query($params);
                             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
                             }

                       }

                       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiCall);
                       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
                       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500);
             // Execute cURL         
             $apiResults = curl_exec($ch);
             // Close cURL
             curl_close($ch);
             // return an JSON *ARRAY* not an object
             return json_decode($apiResults, true);

}
```

[php-ref](https://github.com/digitalnature/php-ref)